# Text is grayed out

Tags: java, intellij-idea

[Grayed out areas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLy5I.jpg)

Hi another question here. I am doing a java tutorial and I am using IntelliJ for my coding. However "randomstring and PINUM is grayed out(see pic) and when hovering the mouse over it says "Field 'randomstring' is never used.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The value is defined, but never used.  IntelliJ is helpfully telling you that you have dead code that you can delete.

You are actually printing out the string "PINUM".  You need to print out the variable:

```
System.out.println(PINUM);  // remove the quotes
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you for the quick answer. However when I run the code I get "PINUM" however the guide shows the number showing up which is in this case 3.1414. not sure why it is dead code and why the number wont come up.

Comment: @Biogrid It should be `System.out.println(PINUM);` instead of `System.out.println("PINUM");` if you want to print the constant value and not the fixed string.

Comment: Damn I feel stupid! Make sense" 

Thanks Crazy Coder!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotation marks around `"PINUM"`

The `""` quotes are used for strings, which means you are requesting the output of the literal string `"PINUM"`, not the variable named `PINUM`

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I am very new at this and thank you for helping!